# Xpath lookup based on XpathNavigator current position

Tags: .net, xpath

I am trying to get some code working that scans a template for XPath expressions and replaces the Xpath with the result. Most of it is fairly straightforward but I am having an issue getting a xpath expression that looks up a value based on the different value based on the current context.

A simplified version of my Code;

```
                   //Iterates through all Posting Opjects
                    XPathNodeIterator loopIter = payload.getXpathList("//FolioInfo/Postings[NetAmount>10]");

                    foreach (XPathNavigator val in loopIter)
                    {

                        string xPathLookup = "//TrxInfo[Code=TrxCode]/Description"  //Returns no result
                        //string xPathLookup = "//TrxInfo[Code=1]/Description"  //Returns "Desc 2"
                        //string xPathLookup = "NetAmount"    //Works Correctly

                        XPathExpression rgxLookup = XPathExpression.Compile(xPathLookup);
                        XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(val.NameTable);
                        rgxLookup.SetContext(manager);

                        string tmpText = val.Evaluate(rgxLookup);  //Simplified - Changes depending on ReturnType

                        //Do stuff
                    }
```

The expression of "//TrxInfo[Code=TrxCode]/Description" is the one I have having problems with. I can replace this with "//TrxInfo[Code=1]/Description" or "//TrxInfo[Code=//FolioInfo/Postings[1]/TrxCode]/Description" and it will work, but I can't get it to recognise the current context to work with just element name.

I have also tried "Code=.TrxCode" which the documentation suggests should work, but no joy.

For background the idea is that a user can configure a template showing the folio postings as they like. There is facility to filter the Postings list, so I can't reliably just iterate through all the Postings with a For loop using position().

Simplified XML

```
<FolioInfo>
    <TrxInfo>
      <Description>Desc 2</Description>
      <Code>1</Code>
    </TrxInfo>
    <TrxInfo>
      <Description>Desc 1</Description>
      <Code>2</Code>
    </TrxInfo>
    <Postings>
      <TrxDate>2016-09-19</TrxDate>
      <TranActionId>123</TranActionId>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <NetAmount>25</NetAmount>
      <TrxCode>1</TrxCode>
    </Postings> 
    <Postings>
      <TrxDate>2016-09-20</TrxDate>
      <TranActionId>321</TranActionId>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <NetAmount>30</NetAmount>
      <TrxCode>2</TrxCode>
    </Postings>     
</FolioInfo>
```

Comment: Your `val` is one of the `Postings` elements. If you evaluate the xpath on it `//TrxInfo[Code='1']/Description` it works ? I expect it to work if you evaluate on the whole xml , not just `Postings` element.

Comment: val is the currently iterated Postings element. I am using the iteration to allow filtering e.g "//FolioInfo/Postings[NetAmount>10]", which means that I can't just evaluate against the whole xml. Yes, //TrxInfo[Code='1'] works, which means that the evaluation can access data outside the current iteration, I just can't get it to work right.